# "Place" starts a clause

Tags: grammar

[image]

> It is such a good place ____ everyone wants to visit ___ it is well-known
>   all over the world.
>
> A. which; that　　　B. as; as
>
> C. as; that　　　　D. that; which

It seems that "place which" is supposed to connect "is." So, the only choice I can choose is D. However, I think none of them is correct. How do you think about it?

Comment: @TypeIA, Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: None of the possible answers make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Which/that" is possible.

> It is such a good place (which everybody wants to visit) that it is known all over the world.

I've inserted parenthesis to emphasise the structure. There is a non-restrictive relative clause describing the place (a good place, which everybody wants to visit) in the middle of a sentence "It is such a good place that it is known all over the world". In this sentence, "that" is a conjunction introducing a clause expressing a consequence.

Some punctuation is needed for this reading, commas should really be used instead of round brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Well D is wrong we can't say .......which it is well-known..
However I believe it could better be 
It is such a good place that everybody wants to visit as it is well-known all over the world 
Or perhaps among your choices (as; as) can be considered correct!